# How to finish Activity from AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my Application I have 3 Activities:

`1. Login`

`2. AsyncTask` (different class)

`3. Welcome`

After receiving all the information in the `Login Activity` it moves to the `AsyncTask Activity`. When the the `AsyncTask` is completed it moves to the `Welcome Activity`. I want to close the `Login Activity` as soon as the `AsyncTask Activity` completes its job..

I am trying to use the following code in the `onPostExecite()` of `AsyncTask`:

`Login.this.finish();`

But I am getting an error of: `No enclosing instance of the type of Login is accessible in scope`..

Please tell me how can i close my `Login Activity` after completing my `AsyncTask`..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Change the order of activities - WelComeActivity + Login

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As AsyncTaskActivity is in separate file than LoginActivity, you cant finish LoginActivity by:

Login.this.finish();

Instead you should pass the Activity Reference as parameter in the AsyncTaskActivity Class, like you can define following constructor:

```
private class AsyncTaskActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Activity mActivity;
    public AsyncTaskActivity(Activity activity)
    {
         super();
         this.mActivity=activity;
    }
}
```

and whenever you want to finish the activity call

```
this.mActivity.finish();
```

Create AsyncTaskActivity's Object in LoginActivity by

```
AsyncTaskActivity asynTask = new AsyncTaskActivity(LoginActivity.this);
```

Comment: I got an error in `AsyncTaskActivity asynTask = new AsyncTask(LoginActivity.this);` <br/>But it works for `AsyncTaskActivity(this).execute()` with some edition.

Comment: oh, sorry it was AsyncTaskActivity asynTask = new AsyncTaskActivity(LoginActivity.this);

Answer (score 2):

Ok . you should call finish() in onPostExcecute method after stating new activity.

**STEPS:**

1)  Login activity

2) Asynac Task(pass application context)

3) Call new Activity

4) finish your login activity in onPostExcecute( context.finish())