# finish() is not executed in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am implementing a class named MyAdapter which extends BaseAdapter. In the class  myAdapter I am implementing a class named AttemptLike which extend AsyncTask. In the class AttemptLike while Implementind doInBackground function I am not able to use finish(); So my app is getting crashed everytime when i invoke the Attemptlike class. So please tell me how to handle the error.

The code goes like this

```
 class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 .
 .
 .
  public class Attemptlike extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
  {
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
  {
  try 
                { 
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somedata1", field1)); 
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somedata2", field2));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("geteventdata", evnt));
                    Log.d("request!", "starting"); 
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest( LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                    // checking log for json response 
                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString()); 
                    // success tag for json 
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); 
                    if (success == 1) 
                    { 
                        Log.d("Successfully Liked!", json.toString());

                        finish();
                        // this finish() method is what i am not able use which is resulting in crashing of app
                    }  
                catch (JSONException e) 
                { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                return null; 
                }  

        }

        new AttemptLogin().execute();
   return convertView;
   }

 }
```

StackTrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: ks.developers.festo, PID: 29568
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method     'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
at ks.developers.festo.list.adapter.MyAdapter$2$1AttemptLike.doInBackground(MyAdapter.java:237)
at ks.developers.festo.list.adapter.MyAdapter$2$1AttemptLike.doInBackground(MyAdapter.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

Comment: `finish()` isn't a method on an `AsyncTask`... Or a `BaseAdapter`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: finish is for activity, so check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12170947/562840) if you want to close the calling activity from the asynctask.

Comment: i have pasted the stack trace here just have a look at it.

Comment: Search this site for "how to read a stack trace."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use finish like that in an `AsyncTask`. It is a member method of activity.

You might want to try putting it inside `runOnUiThread()` or passing the contest to the `AsyncTask` and calling `finish()` using the context.

Havent personally tried either but i bet on the first one to work.

**Update after looking at the stack trace you pasted now:**

You actually have a NPE at this line:

```
Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
```

json is null, so you are not getting the data at all. It is never reaching `finish()` be cause the NPE is thrown much before that in the `toString()` call when you are trying to log the json. First fix that and see if it works. If still doesnt, try one of the above approaches.

Comment: i have pasted the stack trace here just have a look at it

Comment: actually I tried the same work again its working good.And after some time its not working good and is being crashed.

Comment: did not understand the above comment. can you explain what worked and then stopped working again and what did you change that make it momentarily work?

Comment: I havent changed anything i just reinstalled the app and tried agian. It worked good for the first time and later it started to get crashed.

Comment: remove the `log.d` and do a null check for `json` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your result to asynctask#onpostexecute and call finish from there. Finish interacts with the ui thread and must be called from that thread. Your asynctask is executed on another thread. On post execute is executed on the calling thread so finish will work.

Comment: i have pasted the stack trace here just have a look at it

Comment: i have read it and tried that too but that didnt solve the problem.